# How to use [I in vim

Tags: vim

The vim command `[I` shows a list of declarations.  How to do I navigate to one of the items in this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (and by briefly glancing at the manual) - that's not possible with those particular commands available.

However, you can use [:vimgrep](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:vimgrep) to sort of achieve what you're after e.g.:-

```
:vimgrep <C-R><C-W> %
```

And then just use the [quickfix list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix-window) to browse the matches as normal:-

```
:copen, :cnext, :cprev, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Take note of the line numbers. You can use `100G` to jump to line 100, `500G` will jump to line 500, etc.

You could also just press `*` repeatedly to move through the matches (or `#` to move backwards).

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet might be what you are looking for. It shows the list of declarations by `[I` and asks you in the same step to enter the number of the item you want to jump to:

```
nnoremap <silent> [I [I:let nr = input("Item: ")<Bar>if nr != ''<Bar>exe "normal " . nr ."[\t"<Bar>endif<CR>
```